# how can I create a trapezoid shape like below image?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have tried to create this by vector and working fine at lolypop but it's not working at kitkat OS.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="50dp"
android:height="50dp"
android:viewportHeight="100"
android:viewportWidth="100">
<path
    android:pathData="M0 0 L100 0 L75 90 L25 90 Z"
    android:strokeColor="@color/white"
    android:strokeWidth="2"
    android:fillColor="@color/white"/></vector>
```

How can i create it at kitkat os.

Comment: User Android Support Library 23.2 and You’ll be able to use VectorDrawableCompat back to API 7.look at [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: i don't much familiar with vector but i think you should check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965390/large-text-is-going-back-of-imageview