# Large text is going back of Imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image]

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/Chartimg"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
     <TextView
        android:text="Medium Textcbvvvccgcvcvcbcvbvvbcvbvcbvcb"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
        android:id="@+id/InfoView_ItemName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1" />        <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
        android:id="@+id/IvItemID"
        android:layout_below="@id/InfoView_ItemName" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

I am creating litview when the listview item have large text it is going back to the image view here I am posting my code. please give me any solution but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Give some id to imageview like this android:id="@+id/right_icon" and `layout_toLeftOf` in textview it will work fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Chartimg"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/InfoView_ItemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_icon"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Medium Textcbvvvccgcvcvcbcvbvvbcvbvcbvcb"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/IvItemID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/InfoView_ItemName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/right_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use **[android:layout_toLeftOf](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)**

> Positions the right edge of this view to the left of the given anchor
>   view ID. Accommodates right margin of this view and left margin of
>   anchor view.

Answer (score 1):

you should align text left of that image view

i.e
firstly provide id to image view

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

and then add this id to text view and add make text view to left of image view i.e

```
<TextView
        android:text="Medium Textcbvvvccgcvcvcbcvbvvbcvbvcbvcb"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv_arrow"
        android:id="@+id/InfoView_ItemName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

if you have any doubt please ask

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` insest of `RelativeLayout`, because in `LinearLayout` you can divide its child view via `layout_weight`.

try to change your code to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Chartimg"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/InfoView_ItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Medium Textcbvvvccgcvcvcbcvbvvbcvbvcbvcb"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IvItemID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/InfoView_ItemName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a horizontal oriented linearlayout
and set weight for your textview to fill the parent:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/Chartimg"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
     <TextView
        android:text="Medium Textcbvvvccgcvcvcbcvbvvbcvbvcbvcb"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
        android:id="@+id/InfoView_ItemName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1" />        
       <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Chartimg"
        android:id="@+id/IvItemID"
        android:layout_below="@id/InfoView_ItemName" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</LinearLayout>
```